Terraform Import of EBS Volumes Not Reflecting in State
I'm trying to move an EC2 instance from one module to another using Terraform. This EC2 instance has EBS volumes attached to it. When I run terraform import on an EBS volume, Terraform does not actually import it. Here's what I get (in this example, I left the resource ID blank):
terraform import "module.nonprd_database_test.aws_ebs_volume.this[\"0\"]" ''
module.nonprd_database_test.data.aws_kms_key.pn_db_cmk: Reading...
data.aws_caller_identity.current: Reading...
module.nonprd_database_test.data.aws_key_pair.pn_db_pair: Reading...
data.aws_caller_identity.current: Read complete after 0s [id=596695436007]
module.nonprd_database_test.data.aws_kms_key.pn_db_cmk: Read complete after 0s [id=3657dd38-3b36-4ef9-a0c2-e4040343fca0]
module.nonprd_database_test.data.aws_key_pair.pn_db_pair: Read complete after 1s [id=key-04fe82aed54f0c3ea]

Import successful!

The resources that were imported are shown above. These resources are now in your Terraform state and will henceforth be managed by Terraform.

Despite the message stating "Import successful!" and the EBS volumes being listed, the volumes do not appear in the Terraform state. When i run terraform plan it still wants to create them, What could be causing this issue?

For some reason since its in a for_each you need to do this
terraform import "module.nonprd_database_test.aws_ebs_volume.this[\"0\"]" vol-<id> instead of "module.nonprd_database_test.aws_ebs_volume.this["0"]".
Hope this helps someone in future!
